# Empty '/target/test-reports' Folder After Running Java Unit Tests In Play Framework 2.2.6

Tags: scala, junit, playframework-2.0, sbt, playframework-2.2

I am also using SBT version 0.13.0. It's worth mentioning that we cannot upgrade or migrate to a newer version of Play at this time. Whenever I run my test cases for my project via `play test`, the test cases are found and ran correctly:

```
[error] Failed: Total 67, Failed 16, Errors 0, Passed 51
[error] Failed tests:
[error]         package.Testxxx
[error]         package.Testyyy
[error]         package.Testzzz
[error]         package.Testxyz
[error] (test:test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 1526 s, completed Oct 12, 2015 12:00:06 PM
```

However, the created `target/test-reports` folder is empty with no xml files. Normally, the command line print out it sufficient, however I am in the process of putting our code repositories onto a Jenkins server for CI. Since there are no XML files, Jenkins assumes there are no tests. I also have an newer Play app running via Typesafe Activator with SBT 0.13.5 and this application generates the XML reports as expected.

I have read that older versions of SBT do not have built in functionality for generating JUnit XML reports and support was added in [0.13.5](https://github.com/sbt/junit-interface/issues/48) and that newer versions of Play also have their own reporter for JUnit. A proposed workaround (in the link mentioned above) is to have a wrapper plugin that will generate the reports for me. But since the `test-reports` folder is being created already, wouldn't that suggest that JUnit is *trying* to do something with the results? There are some other articles about SBT's JUnit XML reporter and things to add to my build.sbt, but all of these articles are based on having the reports generating already. My problem is they *aren't* being generated. Any and all help on this is greatly appreciated, I have tried searching but nothing I have seen so far seems to be my issue.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Yes. The issue was with Play 2.2. Running the project with Play 2.3 started giving us test reports. They must have included a reporter in either the update of Play or the new sbt version underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with Play 2.2 or the version of SBT it uses.

Running the project with Play 2.3 started giving us test reports. They must have included a reporter in either the update of Play or the new SBT version underneath.

It's worth noting we didn't migrate the code to 2.3. We just ran the app with 2.3 since we were starting new projects at the time.